# R: Difference in expected values of empirical distributions - functional forms unknown

Tags: r, expectations, empirical-distribution

Given a generated two empirical distributions

I am trying to find the expected value of each distribution and then take the difference between these two expected values.

Most questions that I have found include either knowing the functional form or are in Matlab/Python. For example,

[How can I efficiently calculate the binomial cumulative distribution function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095650/how-can-i-efficiently-calculate-the-binomial-cumulative-distribution-function?rq=1)
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105509/integrating-an-empirical-cdf

[Empirical Distribution Function in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36353997/empirical-distribution-function-in-numpy)

Assume that this data is generated from an unknown empirical distribution:

df <- data.frame(x1=rnorm(1000), x2=rnorm(1000,2,1))

Other than randomly sampling and taking the mean of each iteration (i.e. central limit theorem), how would I find the expected value of each distribution?

Comment: Your 2nd link doesn't require either the functional form or Matlab/Python

Comment: I don't understand. What is the issue with just taking the difference of the two means directly?

Comment: Are you sure this is a programming question? You don't outline exactly the computations you want to perform in the question itself. If this is more of a question about what statistical methods to use, then you should probably ask at [stats.se]. But I would still clarify exactly what you are doing. Where did the data come from? What inference are you trying to make exactly?